# extendedBackgroundTaskTime and Store release?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, desktop-bridge

I am a bit confused, as according to the documentation, only personal and enterprise apps are allowed to use this. But it seems like there are apps on the store that do it, and the Windows App Certification kit did not flag my app. Can I submit it to the store without any problems? If not, is there any way to still get approval submit it?

If it is not possible, can an user somehow add this capability if needed after downloading it from the store without it? Like via Powershell?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely submit apps to the Store with this capability. Your app will be subject to an additional onboarding review to ensure you are using the capability for good reasons. I think the documentation wording may need to be updated.